# Animate clip jquery effect with opacity 1 to 0

Tags: jquery, html, css, opacity, clip

This is very simple, i have a box with clip animation and i want to change the opacity from 1 to 0 in the same moment that do the clip effect animation. How can i do?

My jquery code is:

```
$( this ).show(0).delay(700).toggle( "clip" );
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a mix of CSS and jQuery to have a fading effect when the opacity changes:

You could apply this CSS to your element:

```
#your-element {
   opacity: 1;
   transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
   }
```

And then:

```
$( this ).show(0).delay(700).toggle( "clip" ).css('opacity', '0');
```

Comment: No, i want to clip and fade in the same time, not only fade.